# Option menu text color different in android pie 9.0

Tags: android, menu, menuitem, android-9.0-pie, textcolor

I am using below theme:

```
<style name="CaptureTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

In every device, I am getting option menu text color as white with black background, but in android 9.0 (Pie), I am getting background and text color black. Below Pie it is working as expected. First one is correct but second one is not correct. Can anyone please help ? I can't change old theme with new app compat one due to some old implementation.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Solution, that worked for me was adding `<item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>` to application/activity theme:

```
    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>
```